# How to add Multiple Selected check box list in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Example** > [image] (Like this one)
Im beginner for the **MVC**,Im developed the **Multiple list box** , i want to added **Multiple check box** for my list box, How can i do it? give me a solution

**view**

```
 <div class="col-md-3" style="left:-40px;top:-22px;">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.FId, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Fs, "FId", "FCode"), new { size = 8, Class = "form-control", title = "", style = " margin-top:6px;font-size:small;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.FId)
                </div>
```

**QR ViewModel**

```
  public int[] FId { get; set; }

        public MultiSelectList Fds { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you mean _multiple check box for my list box_? Do you want checkboxes inside the `<select>` element?

Comment: yeah i  need ,please check example pic

Comment: You cant add checkboxes to a `select`. Just use a div with a collection of checkboxes and associated text (set a height and overflow if you want scrolling)

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-checkboxlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Comment: thanks for the help,